# what is this usage of alert in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, xss

Here is a xss code:

```
<img src=x onerror="javascript:window.onerror=alert;throw 1">
```

I can't understand the usage of `alert` here. Why we don't need parentheses after the `alert`? And I can't understand the behavior of browser. The browser will pop up a box and dislplay `Uncaught 1`. It looks like that the browser first pop up an alert box and then fill the exception string into the box. However, I am not quite sure how this happens. BTW, I tested this in chrome.

Comment: _An alert box is often used if you want to make sure information comes through to the user._  what is your actual issue here

Comment: It looks like this specific example demonstrates how it is possible to call functions without using any parenthesis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `window.onerror` itself is a function. You can say it as a function name or better, **function reference**. And alert is also a name of the function, which can be called as funtion reference.

So, they are mapping the `onerror` with `alert`, i.e., when the `onerror` event takes place, there will be an alert.

The `window.onerror` being an event handler, and `alert` is something that alerts whatever sent into the parameter, now the `onerror` event handler sends the event information to the `alert` and yes, you get what's the error, when an error occurs.

More information about parameters and working of [`window.onerror`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror). Their syntax is:

```
window.onerror = funcRef;
```

Where the `funcRef` is referred to `alert()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I still can't understand why `throw 1` caused `Uncaught 1` displayed in the alert box?

Comment: The `throw` is for error handling. `throw` is meant to throw an error and we need to handle the error using `try ... catch` block.

Comment: The `throw` statement throws a user-defined `exception`. Execution of the current function **will stop** (the statements after `throw` won't be executed), and control will be passed to the first `catch` block in the call stack. If no `catch` block exists among caller functions, the program will terminate.

Comment: But what's weird is that the `exception` threw by user is shown **in the alert box**. How could this happen? I'm sorry I am confused...

Comment: Boss, just now I said, `alert` says anything passed to it and the `onerror` sends the exception text. So alert alerts the exception text. Got it?

Comment: Yes, I think this script is a demo trying to avoid using parentheses to bypass some filter.